# No Rows Returned from Query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am trying to write a query that For any scheduled event,
show details of the event, the chosen customer and the details of all
the equipment required. Equipment can be either in house equipment or hired equipment. In house and hired equipment are two different tables in the database. For the instance of the event information and customer information there will be inhouse equipment and hired equipment.

The query I have written uses the union technique. The query returns "no rows returned" even though there is clearly information in the tables as shown in the pictures below.

I have used the AS function to rename the different columns in the two tables and null for the extra columns such as rental fee of hired equipment.  Can anyone assist?

This is my code

```
COLUMN E_ID FORMAT A7
COLUMN E_NAME FORMAT A35
COLUMN E_STIME FORMAT A21
COLUMN E_FTIME FORMAT A21
COLUMN E_COST FORMAT 99999.99
COLUMN ET_ET_ID FORMAT A5
COLUMN ET_DESC FORMAT A10
COLUMN V_V_ID FORMAT A5
COLUMN V_NAME FORMAT A10
COLUMN C_C_ID FORMAT A5
COLUMN C_FNAME FORMAT A10
COLUMN C_LNAME FORMAT A7
COLUMN C_ORG FORMAT A20
COLUMN C_CNUM FORMAT 9999999
COLUMN EQ_ID FORMAT A5
COLUMN EQ_DESC FORMAT A30
COLUMN EQ_TYPE FORMAT A15
COLUMN EQ_AMT FORMAT A3
COLUMN RENT_FEE FORMAT 9999.99
COLUMN SU_NAME FORMAT A35
BREAK ON E_ID ON E_NAME ON C_C_ID ON C_FNAME ON C_LNAME ON C_ORG ON C_CNUM ON E_STIME ON E_FTIME ON E_COST ON ET_ET_ID ON ET_DESC ON V_V_ID ON V_NAME
SELECT E_ID, E_NAME, EVENT.C_C_ID ,C_FNAME, C_LNAME, C_ORG, C_CNUM, E_STIME, E_FTIME, E_COST, EVENT.ET_ET_ID, EVENTTYPE.ET_DESC, EVENT.V_V_ID, VENUE.V_NAME, INEQUIPMENT.IE_ID AS EQ_ID, INEQUIPMENT.IE_DESC AS EQ_DESC, INEQUIPMENT.IE_TYPE AS EQ_TYPE, EVENT_INEQUIPMENT.IE_AMT AS EQ_AMT, NULL AS RENT_FEE, NULL AS SU_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER, EVENT, EVENT_INEQUIPMENT, INEQUIPMENT, VENUE, EVENTTYPE
WHERE EVENT.E_ID = 'E000001'
AND EVENT.V_V_ID = VENUE.V_ID
AND EVENT.ET_ET_ID = EVENTTYPE.ET_ID
AND EVENT.C_C_ID = CUSTOMER.C_ID
AND EVENT.E_ID = EVENT_INEQUIPMENT.IE_IE_ID
AND EVENT_INEQUIPMENT.IE_IE_ID = INEQUIPMENT.IE_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT E_ID, E_NAME, EVENT.C_C_ID ,C_FNAME, C_LNAME, C_ORG, C_CNUM, E_STIME, E_FTIME, E_COST, EVENT.ET_ET_ID, EVENTTYPE.ET_DESC, EVENT.V_V_ID, VENUE.V_NAME, EXEQUIPMENT.XE_ID AS EQ_ID, EXEQUIPMENT.XE_DESC AS EQ_DESC, EXEQUIPMENT.XE_TYPE AS EQ_TYPE, EVENT_EXEQUIPMENT.XE_AMT AS EQ_AMT, EXEQUIPMENT.R_FEE AS RENT_FEE, SUPPLIER.SU_NAME AS SU_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER, EVENT, EVENT_EXEQUIPMENT, EXEQUIPMENT, SUPPLIER, VENUE, EVENTTYPE
WHERE EVENT.E_ID = 'E000001'
AND EVENT.V_V_ID = VENUE.V_ID
AND EVENT.ET_ET_ID = EVENTTYPE.ET_ID
AND EVENT.C_C_ID = CUSTOMER.C_ID
AND EVENT.E_ID = EVENT_EXEQUIPMENT.XE_XE_ID
AND EVENT_EXEQUIPMENT.XE_XE_ID = EXEQUIPMENT.XE_ID
AND EXEQUIPMENT.SU_SU_ID = SUPPLIER.SU_ID;
```

you can clearly see from the images that the tables have data for E_ID = E000001

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a series of inner joins. That means, for each table being joined together you're requesting only rows that appear in both tables based on the join condition. So, it follows that if you're getting no rows returned out of the main query, somewhere in your tables you have data which doesn't match the join conditions for your specific e_id.

For a start, I would rewrite your query using the ANSI join syntax, like so:

```
SELECT e_id,
       e_name,
       event.c_c_id,
       c_fname,
       c_lname,
       c_org,
       c_cnum,
       e_stime,
       e_ftime,
       e_cost,
       event.et_et_id,
       eventtype.et_desc,
       event.v_v_id,
       venue.v_name,
       inequipment.ie_id        AS eq_id,
       inequipment.ie_desc      AS eq_desc,
       inequipment.ie_type      AS eq_type,
       event_inequipment.ie_amt AS eq_amt,
       NULL                     AS rent_fee,
       NULL                     AS su_name
FROM   event
       INNER JOIN customer ON event.c_c_id = customer.c_id
       INNER JOIN event_inequipment ON event.e_id = event_inequipment.ie_ie_id
       INNER JOIN inequipment ON event_inequipment.ie_ie_id = inequipment.ie_id
       INNER JOIN venue ON event.v_v_id = venue.v_id
       INNER JOIN eventtype ON event.et_et_id = eventtype.et_id
WHERE  event.e_id = 'E000001'
UNION ALL
SELECT e_id,
       e_name,
       event.c_c_id,
       c_fname,
       c_lname,
       c_org,
       c_cnum,
       e_stime,
       e_ftime,
       e_cost,
       event.et_et_id,
       eventtype.et_desc,
       event.v_v_id,
       venue.v_name,
       exequipment.xe_id        AS eq_id,
       exequipment.xe_desc      AS eq_desc,
       exequipment.xe_type      AS eq_type,
       event_exequipment.xe_amt AS eq_amt,
       exequipment.r_fee        AS rent_fee,
       supplier.su_name         AS su_name
FROM   event
       INNER JOIN customer ON event.c_c_id = customer.c_id
       INNER JOIN event_exequipment ON event.e_id = event_exequipment.xe_xe_id
       INNER JOIN exequipment ON event_exequipment.xe_xe_id = exequipment.xe_id
       INNER JOIN supplier ON exequipment.su_su_id = supplier.su_id;
       INNER JOIN venue ON event.v_v_id = venue.v_id
       INNER JOIN eventtype ON event.et_et_id = eventtype.et_id
WHERE  event.e_id = 'E000001';
```

Once you've done that, you can easily either convert the joins to be left outer joins or simply comment them out altogether, to allow you to diagnose which joins aren't returning any rows.

With a query like this, it often helps to start with the basic table and then add the joins in one-by-one until you see where the problem lies.